# Android Read and Write Without Requesting Permission - Theta

Tags: android, theta360

i need permission read and write for my plugin, i try a lot of things.

In manifest

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE" />
```

but not working after `v23` according to others posts, so i try with `requestPermission` but my app crash and in real use case i don't have any interface.

I'm using [RICOH THETA Plug-in SDK](https://github.com/ricohapi/theta-plugin-sdk)

I'm trying to use `BitmapFactory` and got this error

```
E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100RICOH/R0010156.JPG (Permission denied)
```

If someone has any idea how to do it.
Thanks.

Comment: Can you post exception logs too?

Comment: E/BitmapFactory: Unable to decode stream: java.io.FileNotFoundException: /storage/emulated/0/DCIM/100RICOH/R0010156.JPG (Permission denied)

Comment: thanks, can you also post how you are requesting permission and how you are using BitmapFactory?

Comment: in MainActivity on create

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Don't worry. THETA Plug-in store grants all permission automatically on instal time. Users do not need to grant permissions manually in actual use case. You need to grant permissions manually only for development time.

The [official document](https://api.ricoh/docs/theta-plugin/how-to-use/#declaration-of-permissions) describes that

> #### Declaration of Permissions
>
> When installing from the RICOH THETA store, based on the protection level set in the manifest file, permission is automatically granted. During development, use an application that displays the screen such as Vysor, and grant permission from the application settings or from a plug-in dialog window.

Answer (score 0):

You have to give permission manually in android 6 and above use dexter library
Link https://github.com/Karumi/Dexter

Comment: I would not suggest to add an external library, only for handling permissions. You'll depend on the library, instead of learning the proper way.

Comment: I tried but the application crashed, I think this library use pop-up request request asking the user to choose the permission, if so it is not the library I need.

Answer (score 0):

in first you should check android version

```
if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
        if (ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED &&
                ContextCompat.checkSelfPermission(this, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE) == PackageManager.PERMISSION_GRANTED {

           // do work

        } else {

            String[] permissions = new String[]{Manifest.permission.READ_EXTERNAL_STORAGE, Manifest.permission.WRITE_EXTERNAL_STORAGE};
            if (Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.M) {
                requestPermissions(permissions, 100);
            }
        }
    } else {

                      // do work
    }
```

Comment: I tried and it goes to the level of String[] permissions = .... and when it's run `requestPermissions()` the app crash

Comment: send me a screenshot from logcat (blue lines)

Comment: it's impossible :)))
when the app crashed, the error is shown in logcat by blue color

Comment: your blue line is `Debug` mod? can you try dl SDK and put your code in and run in any android smartphone, normally has the same behaviour